# Search on array of items by multiple filter

Tags: angular

I got a list of employees like this from an api-
246

```
[{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, …]
[0 … 99]
0:
  employee_code: "10001338"
  employee_name: "ABC"
  staff_id: "1720"
```

In ts file, search by `employee_name` and `employee_code` BUT only `employee_code` working

```
getEmployees() {
  this._service.getAllEmployees().subscribe(res => {
    this.employees = res.data;
    this.employeeSearch();
  })
}

employeeSearch(): void {
  this.employeeSearchArray = [...this.employees];

    
  this.parentController
    .valueChanges
    .pipe(debounceTime(500))
    .subscribe((value: string) => {
       if (value.length > 0) {
         this.employees = this.employeeSearchArray.filter((v: 
    {employee_employee_name: string}) =>  v.employee_employee_name 
           ? 
  v.employee_employee_name.toLowerCase().includes(value.toLowerCase()) 
           : null);

    this.employees = this.employeeSearchArray.filter((v: {employee_code: string}) =>  
      v.employee_code ? v.employee_code.toLowerCase().includes(value.toLowerCase()) : 
    null);
       } else {
         this.employees = this.employeeSearchArray;
       }
    });
}
```

How can I search by both properties in this array?

Answer (score 1):

That's happen because you use assignment operator (`=`) in both case. First you searched by name and then you searched by code and **assign** the result (only code result) to `employees`. So you override the first search (search by name) history.

Try this one:

```
this.employees = this.employeeSearchArray.filter(
                   v => v.employee_name.toLowerCase().includes(value.toLowerCase()) ||  
                        v.employee_code.toLowerCase().includes(value.toLowerCase()));
```

Comment: Thnx @Alireza for your reply. push method is not working here actually but in second way it is working. it can be slightly reduced to-
 if (value.length > 0 ) {
    this.employees = this.employeeSearchArray.filter(v =>  v.employee_name.toLowerCase().includes(value.toLowerCase())
    || v.employee_code.toLowerCase().includes(value.toLowerCase()));
    }

Comment: If you use *ngFor you're right `push` method does not trigger change action. I'm going to edit my answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
 handleFilter(value) {
       this.employees = this.employeeSearchArray.filter((s) => 
       s.employee_name.toLowerCase().indexOf(value.toLowerCase()) !== -1);
}
```

You can also use this using search by name and pass the value to the handleFilter function value parameter.